# Find files in linux and exclude specific directories

Tags: find

I have a find looking like this:

```
rm -f crush-all.js
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" ! -name "*console*" \) | while read line
do
   cat "$line" >> crush-all.js
   echo >> crush-all.js
done
```

I'd like to add to exclude a directory called "test" in the find but I can't seem to figure out how to add "-type d" somehow. How'd I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `-path` option to find and combine it with the `-not` operator.

```
find . ! -path "*/test/*" -type f -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min-*" ! -name "*console*"
```

Please note two things

- `-path` must come as the first argument
- the pattern matches the whole filename, so `-path test` will not match anything, ever

By the way, I'm not sure why you are using parentheses, it doesn't make a difference. It is only used for precedence, for constructs such as `! \( -name '*bla*' -name '*foo*' \)` (that is, do not find things that have both `bla` and `foo`).

A further refinement: no need to use the bash loop, you can simply do

```
find . ... -exec cat {} \; -exec echo \;
```

where ... are the other arguments to `find`.

Answer (score 4):

```
find / -path ./test -prune -o ...
```

Rename `./test` to fit the location of you test directory.

Comment: In this case, do not forget add -print action (because -print is not default action) after -o option

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what I think `@CharlesClavadetscher` was going for with his answer. If you omit a path with `-not -path ...` <kbd>find</kbd> will continue descending the path.  Instead, using `-prune` will stop it from descending further into the omitted path, making it faster. So you can do something like

```
find . -path '*test/*' -prune -o -type f -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" ! -name "*console*" -print
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with grep like this (the folder here is named test_folder):

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" ! -name "*console*" \) | grep -v "/path/to/test_folder/" | while read line
```

or if your find returns relative path :

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" ! -name "*console*" \) | grep -v "./relative_path/to/test_folder/" | while read line
```

or if you want all folders that has the same name but with different path

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" ! -name "*console*" \) | grep -v "/test_folder/" | while read line
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I use "not wholename" when I'm just searching for a file.  *-name* tests the actual filename, but *-wholename* tests the full path.
So adding an ignore for test to the question above:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" ! -name "*-min*" ! -name "*console*" \) ! -wholename "*test*"
```