# How to exclude/ignore hidden files and directories in a wildcard-embedded "find" search?

Tags: command-line, find

Starting from (notice the **wildcards before and after** "some text")

```
find . -type f -name '*some text*'
```

how can one exclude/ignore all hidden files and directories?

I've already [been googling for far too long](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-command-exclude-ignore-files/), came across some -prune and ! (exclamation mark) parameters, but no fitting (and parsimonious) example *which just worked*.

*Piping* `|` to `grep` would be an option and I'd also welcome examples of that; but *primarily* I'm interested in a brief one-liner (or a couple of stand-alone one-liners, illustrating different ways of achieving the same command-line goal) *just* using [**`find`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/find.1.html).

ps: [Find files in linux and exclude specific directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206277/find-files-in-linux-and-exclude-specific-directories) seems closely related, but a) is not accepted yet and b) is related-but-different-and-distinct, but c) may provide inspiration and help pinpoint the confusion!

**Edit**

`find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f -name "whatever"`, works. The regex looks for "anything, then a slash, then a dot, then anything" (i.e. all hidden files and folders including their subfolders), and the "!" negates the regex.

Comment: Doesn't help with what you asked in your edit but take a look at my question and its answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/69164/15760 and also the link in the answer.

Comment: Related: [Exclude hidden files when searching with Unix/Linux find?](http://superuser.com/questions/152958/exclude-hidden-files-when-searching-with-unix-linux-find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>The **answer** I originally posted as an "edit" to my original question above:</sup>

`find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f -name "whatever"`, works. The regex looks for "anything, then a slash, then a dot, then anything" (i.e. all hidden files and folders including their subfolders), and the "!" negates the regex.

Comment: Similar, but for only the current folder: `find . \( ! -regex './\..*' \) -type f -maxdepth 1 -print`

Comment: This fails if the start path contains dots in it such as `find ../buildfiles <expressions>`

Answer (score 233):

This prints all files that are descendants of your directory, skipping hidden files and directories:

```
find . -not -path '*/.*'
```

So if you're looking for a file with `some text` in its name, and you want to skip hidden files and directories, run:

```
find . -not -path '*/.*' -type f -name '*some text*'
```

### Explanation:

The `-path` option runs checks a pattern against the entire path string. `*` is a wildcard, `/` is a directory separator, `.` is a dot (hidden filenames start with a dot on Linux), and `*` is another wildcard. `-not` means don't select files that match this test.

I don't think that `find` is smart enough to avoid recursively searching hidden directories in the previous command, so if you need speed, use `-prune` instead, like this:

```
 find . -type d -path '*/.*' -prune -o -not -name '.*' -type f -name '*some text*' -print
```

Comment: Note with the last one that you need that `-print` at the end! Also, not sure if `-name '\.*' would be more efficient instead of `-path` (because the path is searching subpaths, but these will be pruned out)

Comment: What's the special meaning of `.` in this context?

Comment: @frostschutz Actually, come to think of it, I may be wrong about `.` having special meaning.

Comment: @Flimm yup, no need to escape `.`. As far as I'm aware, only these need to be escaped: `*`, `?`, and `[]`.

Comment: This is good, but could be substantially simplified. See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127030/884989)

Comment: I recently found a problem with a pattern such as this. If your search path contains a (.) in, then it all gets filtered. For example `find ../buildfiles` The double dots for going backwards will trigger the '*/.*' pattern because the result will be `../buildfiles/foo, ../buildfiles/bar, ../buildfiles/etc`

Answer (score 16):

This is one of the few means of excludes dot-files that also works correctly on BSD, Mac and Linux:

```
find "$PWD" -name ".*" -prune -o -print
```

- `$PWD` print the full path to the current directory so that the path does not start with `./`
- `-name ".*" -prune` matches any files or directories that start with a dot and then don't descend
- `-o -print` means print the file name if the previous expression did not match anything. Using `-print` or `-print0` causes all other expressions to not print by default.

Comment: Please explain / elaborate on "alarmingly complicated"; the answers already given and your answer seem to give evidence to the contrary...?

Comment: "alarmingly complicated" is probably excessive. I reworded the answer to get to the point. I think the answer I posted is difficult to understand and is hard to see without a very careful reading of the man page. If you are _only_ using GNU find then there are more possible solutions.

Comment: `-o ... -print` is helpful. For my use, I now have `find ... '!' -name . -name '.*' -prune -o ... -print`, which was more convenient than including $PWD.

Comment: tried using it in combination with a dir name of "." - did not result in anything.

Comment: this seems like the ticket to me.  fwiw I'd consider leaving off the `"$PWD"` thing. While it may be what you prefer, I think it's orthogonal to the question.

Comment: What's particularly brilliant about this one is that it's running around 40% faster on my `~/` than `find . -not -path '*/\.*'` thanks to that `-prune` term.

Answer (score 7):

```
find $DIR -not -path '*/\.*' -type f \( ! -iname ".*" \)
```

Excludes all hidden directories, and hidden files under $DIR

Comment: This is the perfect answer. It recursively finds all files but excludes line items for directories and hidden files. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to use `find` for that. Just use globstar in shell it-self, like:

```
echo **/*foo*
```

or:

```
ls **/*foo*
```

where `**/` represents any folder recursively and `*foo*` any file which has `foo` in its name.

By default using `ls` will print file names excluding hidden files and directories.

If you don't have globbing enabled, do it by `shopt -s globstar`.

<sup>Note: [A new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) works in Bash 4, zsh and similar shells.</sup>

---

Example:

```
$ mkdir -vp a/b/c/d
mkdir: created directory 'a'
mkdir: created directory 'a/b'
mkdir: created directory 'a/b/c'
mkdir: created directory 'a/b/c/d'
$ touch a/b/c/d/foo a/b/c/d/bar  a/b/c/d/.foo_hidden a/b/c/d/foo_not_hidden
$ echo **/*foo*
a/b/c/d/foo  a/b/c/d/foo_not_hidden
```

Comment: You don't need `ls` for that! `echo **/*foo*`

Comment: @kenorb  (and @kevin-cox).  Could you be a bit more verbose? Why would globstar ( = * ) work here and how? What does the slash / do?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty `/` means folder, it separates directories from the filename. `*` basically represents everything.

Comment: @kenorb yes-but: how does that one-liner help with the original question?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Clarified and added example. It helps by finding files ignoring the hidden one.

Comment: Great alternative and comprehensive/thorough yet concise ;) answer! Thanks!

Comment: This depends on the shell supporting this feature. I think it works in Bash and Zsh. It also depends on globbing not matching hidden files, which it doesn't by default, unless `dotglob` is enabled (Bash: `shopt -s dotglob` ; Zsh: `setopt dotglob`)

Comment: `echo **/*foo*` just echoes literal `**/*foo*` for me

Comment: ...turns out because I was in Bash 3.2 and `**` ("globstar") was added in 4 https://askubuntu.com/a/1010708/62915

Answer (score 2):

@Flimm's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/318211/884989) is good, *particularly because it prevents find from descending into hidden directories*. I prefer this simplification:

Generally to exclude all hidden paths (regular files, directories, etc):

```
find <start-point> -path '*/.*' -prune -o <expression> -print
```

For example, using your working directory as the start point, and `-name '*some text*'` as the expression:

```
find . -path '*/.*' -prune -o -name '*some text*' -print
```

In contrast to what @Flimm's answer suggests, no hidden files or hidden directories is the simple case. The `-path '*/.*'` expression is true for any path (regular files, directories, etc) that has a `.` immediately after your file separator, `/`. So this line will prune both hidden files and directories.

Allowing hidden files while excluding hidden directories is the case that requires a further filter. This is where you would include `-type d` in the the expression being pruned.

```
find <start-point> -type d -path '*/.*' -prune -o <expression> -print
```

For example:

```
find . -type d -path '*/.*' -prune -o -name '*some text*' -print
```

In this case `-type d -path '*/.*'` is `true` only for directories, and so only directories are pruned.

Answer (score 2):

This usually works too

```
find * [expression]
```

Using * shell wildcard for input all paths from working directory, usually * wildcard doesn't expand to hidden files but this could be changed in the shell options.
Example:

```
find /path/* -iname file -mtime -3
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant on https://askubuntu.com/a/749708/321070

```
find  -name '.?*' -prune -o -print
```

Instead of setting the directory to a full path, instead filter out things that mat ch `.?*` - a literal dot, any character, and then 0 or more characters.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I tested this command and got everything listed. I kinda understand your idea but things need to improve a little.

Comment: It works fine for me using `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0`. Can you share a filename that is causing a false positive?

Comment: My English sucks (or I am tired) and the question meant two cases, "ignore A and B". Second case, find "hidden files and hidden directories" yours is perfect. While reviewing your first post, I could only see your answer and the title of OP. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

`find` has neat logic switches such as `-and` and `-not` you can use them to your advantage to find a matching file with two rules like so:

```
$ touch non_hidden_file.txt .hidden_file.txt somethings/.another_hidden_file.txt                                                 

$ find . -type f -name '*hidden_file*' -and \( -not -name ".*" \)                            
./non_hidden_file.txt
```

As you can see, `find` uses two rules  `-name '*hidden_file*'` and `-and \( -not -name ".*" \)` to find those filenames that match both conditions - filename with `hidden_file` in it but without leading dot. Note the slashes in front of parenthesis - they are used to define parenthesis as `find` arguments rather defining a subshell (which is what parenthesis mean otherwise without slashes)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pwd
/home/victoria

$ find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | sort
/home/victoria/new
/home/victoria/new1
/home/victoria/new2
/home/victoria/new3
/home/victoria/new3.md
/home/victoria/new.md
/home/victoria/package.json
/home/victoria/Untitled Document 1
/home/victoria/Untitled Document 2

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | sed 's/^\.\///g' | sort
new
new1
new2
new3
new3.md
new.md
package.json
Untitled Document 1
Untitled Document 2
```

**Notes:**

- `.` : current folder
- remove `-maxdepth 1` to search recursively
- `-type f` : find files, not directories (`d`)
- `-not -path '*/\.*'` : do not return `.hidden_files`
- `sed 's/^\.\///g'` : remove the prepended `./` from the result list

Answer (score 0):

This answer [to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/318211/4804), is the only one that gave me the same results I'd get if I went into each folder, and then did an `ls`. I had to add `-type f` for it to fully work.

```
find . -not -path '*/\.*' -type f
```