# gzip all files with specific extensions

Tags: gzip

I'm trying to gzip all files on ubuntu that have the file extension .css, .html or .js. in a top directory and all subdirectories. I want to keep the original files and overwrite the .gz file, if already existing.

So when I have n files, I want to keep these n files and create additional n archive files. Not just one.

My try was to run a script that looks like this:

```
gzip -rkf *.css
gzip -rkf *.html
... one line for each file extension
```

First: I need to have one line in that script for each file extension I want to gzip. That's ok, but I hope to find a better way

Second and more important: It does not work. Although -r should do the job, the subdirectories are unchanged. The gzip file is only created in the top directory.

What am I missing here?

Btw: The following is a bug in the verbose output, right? When using -k and -v option

```
-k, --keep        keep (don't delete) input files
-v, --verbose     verbose mode
```

The verbose output says it replaces the file, although "replace" means that the original file does not exist after the replace. Anyway, THis is only the output thing.

```
$ ls
  index.html      subdir1  testfile      testfile.css.gz
  javaclass.java  subdir2  testfile.css
$ gzip -fkv *.css
  testfile.css:   6.6% -- replaced with testfile.css.gz
$ ls
  index.html      subdir1  testfile      testfile.css.gz
  javaclass.java  subdir2  testfile.css
```

Comment: `-r` works as designed. From [man gzip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip): _Travel the directory structure recursively. **If any of the file names specified on the command line are directories**, gzip will descend into the directory and compress all the files it finds there (or decompress them in the case of gunzip)._ (emphasis mine)

Comment: Ok. So -r would enter a directory with the name XYZ.css. Then recursion is not designed as I expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do that with a for loop to find every file then compress it:

```
for i in `find | grep -E "\.css$|\.html$"`; do gzip "$i" ; done
```

Comment: Thank you! Though the `-r` option does not work, `-k` and `-f` are working, so I can use them like this: for i in `find | grep -E "\.css$|\.html$"`; do gzip -vkf "$i" ; done`

Comment: @Sadik: Be careful! This approach won't work if any of the files' names contains a space.

Comment: Could you explain why not?

Comment: @Sadik: `\`...\`` provides a string, not a list. `for` uses the internal field separator (`$IFS`) to decide where that string should be split. By default, it splits at linefeeds, tabs and spaces, so if you have a file called `new style.css`, the commands `gzip new` and `gzip style.css` will be executed.

Comment: @Sadik, Dennis is right, as quick workaround you can run `export IFS=$'\n'` just before the `for` loop.

Comment: @mndo That's better than nothing, but filenames can contain a newline (`$'\n'`), and then it still breaks. The only characters a filename cannot contain are `/` (but it appears in `find` output for the same reason: it's the path separator) and the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). Output of `find` with the `-print0` action, which uses nulls instead of newlines, may be safely piped to `xargs -0`, which is probably the only common situation where it's both correct and useful to pipe a list of paths from `find` to a command that causes each one to be operated on.

Answer (score 19):

I would use

```
find /path/to/dir \( -name '*.css' -o -name '*.html' \) -exec gzip --verbose --keep {} \;
```

Change `name` to `iname` if you want to match the extensions case-insensitively (i.e. include `.CSS` and/or `.HTML` extensions). You can omit the `/path/to/dir` if you want to start the recursive search from the current directory.

Comment: For those who may be wondering about the `--keep` switch, yes, it causes the original files to be retained. Omit it if you want to them to be deleted once gzipped.

Answer (score 6):

To get the list of files:

```
find -type f | grep -P '\.js|\.html|\.css'
```

And to gzip all those files:

```
find -type f | grep -P '\.js|\.html|\.css' | tar cvzf archive.gz -T -
```

Comment: Wouldn't this `tar` the *list of*  files as output by `find`, rather than the files themselves?

Comment: I edited my question to make clear that I want to have an archive file for each css,html or js file.

Comment: @Jos no with the `-T` option `tar` processes the input as filenames.

Comment: @chaos Ah, thank you. I learned something today.

Answer (score 4):

## You can use globstar.

*With the `globstar` shell option enabled, all you need is `gzip -vk **/*.{css,html}`.*

The Bash shell has a [`globstar`](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) option that lets you write recursive [globs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) with `**`. `shopt -s globstar` enables it. But you might not want to do that for other commands you run later, so you can run it and your `gzip`  command in a [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell) instead.

This command `gzip`s all `.css` and `.html` files in the current directory any of its subdirectories, any of *their* subdirectories, etc., keeping the original files (`-k`) and telling you what it's doing (`-v`):

```bash
(shopt -s globstar; gzip -vk **/*.{css,html})
```

If you want to match filenames case-insensitively so those extensions with some or all letters capitalized are included, then you can also enable the `nocaseglob` shell option:

```bash
(shopt -s globstar nocaseglob; gzip -vk **/*.{css,html})
```

`;` separates the two commands, and the outer `(` `)` cause them to be run in a subshell. Setting a shell option in a subshell does not cause it to be set in the calling shell. If you *do* want to enable `globstar` then you can run `shopt -s globstar`; then you can just run the command:

```
gzip -vk **/*.{css,html}
```

You can disable `globstar` with `shopt -u globstar`. You can check if it's currently enabled with `shopt globstar`.

#### How It Works

The key to how this `gzip` command works is that the shell performs expansions on it to produce a list of each file in the directory hierarchy with a matching name, then passes each of these filenames as arguments to `gzip`.

- [Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) turns `**/*.{css,html}` into `**/*.css **/*.html`.
- Then [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) expands those two patterns into the names of files accessible under the current directory (`**`, due to `globstar`) whose filenames consist of anything (`*`) followed by the specified suffix (`.css` or `.html` in this case).

This does not match files whose names [start with `.`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) or those that reside in directories named this way. You probably don't have any such HTML and CSS files and, if you do, you probably don't want to include them. But if you do want to include them, then you can match them explicitly depending on your needs. For example, changing `**/*.{css,html}` to `**/{,.}*.{css,html}` includes files that start with `.` while still *not* searching in folders that do.

If you want both files whose names start with `.` and files in directories whose names start with `.` to be included, there's a cleaner and simpler way: enable the `dotglob` shell option.

```bash
(shopt -s globstar dotglob; gzip -vk **/*.{css,html})
```

Or if you want case-insensitive matching *and* matching of filenames that start with `.`:

```bash
(shopt -s globstar nocaseglob dotglob; gzip -vk **/*.{css,html})
```

#### It's possible, though very rare, for `**` to expand to something too long.

If you have a *huge* number of files named this way, then this may fail with an error message explaining that the shell cannot build the command line because it would be too long. (Even with thousands of files, this *usually* is not a problem.)

`gzip` won't be called at all, so you won't get a half-done job.

If this error happens, or if you're worried about it, you can use `find` with `-exec`, either as [**steeldriver describes**](https://askubuntu.com/a/496441/22949) (with `{} \;`) or as I describe below (with `{} +`).

## You can use `find` with the `-exec` action and `+` for efficiency.

The `gzip` command supports being given names of multiple files to be compressed. But this `find` command, although it works well and won't be slow unless you have *many* files, runs the `gzip` command once for *each*  file:

```bash
find . \( -name \*.css -o -name \*.html \) -exec gzip -vk {} \;
```

This works, and you can definitely use it. (`.` searches from the current directory. Besides that, it's really a slightly different way of writing the command in [**steeldriver's very good answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/496441/22949); you can use whichever style you prefer.)

You can also make `find` pass multiple filenames to `gzip` and run it only as many times as necessary--which is nearly always just once. To do that, **use `+` instead of `\;`**. The `+` argument should come just after `{}`. `find` replaces `+` with additional filenames, if any.

```bash
find . \( -name \*.css -o -name \*.html \) -exec gzip -vk {} +
```

It's fine to use `+` even if there are only a few matching files, and when there are many of them, it can be noticeably faster than having a separate `gzip` invocation for each file.

As [steeldriver mentions](https://askubuntu.com/a/496441/22949), you can use `-iname` instead of `-name` to match files whose name end like `.css` or `.html` but with different capitalization. This corresponds to enabling `nocaseglob` in the `globstar`-based method described above.

Finally, you probably don't have any matching files or directories that start with `.`. But if you do, `find` automatically includes them. If you want to *exclude* them (as happens with the `globstar`-based method detailed above when `dotglob` is off), [**you can**](https://askubuntu.com/a/318211/22949):

```
find . -not -path '*/.*' \( -name \*.css -o -name \*.html \) -exec gzip -vk {} +
```

The `globstar`-based way described above is simpler to write, especially if you're excluding directories and files that begin with `.`, since that's the default.

## What *not* to do...

Filenames can contain any character except the path separator `/` and the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). Many techniques that break on weird filenames exist, and they are usually *more complicated* than techniques that always just work. So I suggest avoiding them even when you know (or think you know) they're okay in your specific situation. And of course you *must* not use them if you might have filenames with characters that may be treated specially, including spaces.

It is possible to safely pipe the output of `find` to another command that processes it **if you use `-print0` or a similar action to cause it to place a null character between paths instead of a newline**, and not otherwise. Filenames can contain newlines (though I discourage you from deliberately naming files with them). A `find` command with the `-print` action--including find commands with no explicit action, since then `-print` is the default--does not produce output that can safely be piped or otherwise provided to another command that performs an action on the files.

The output `find` produces with the `-print0` action may safely be piped to `xargs -0` (the `-0` flag tells `xargs` to expect null-separated input).

Answer (score 2):

I used [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/496441/22949), but I like to complete it with the `--best` and `--force` options.

`cd` into any folder and type this code. All your matching files will be gzipped.

```bash
find . \( -name '*.css' -o -name '*.js' \) -exec gzip --verbose --keep --best --force {} \;
```

- Use `--best` for best compression ratio.
- Use `--force` for overwriting without asking if there is already a gzipped file.

Answer (score 0):

To zip all files in a folder/subfolder recursively:

```
gzip -r `find . -type f -name "*.html"`
```

To unzip:

```
gunzip -r `find . -type f -name "*.gz"`
```

Comment: This [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) based method will frequently break, and quite badly. The problem is that filenames containing spaces or other whitespace will be split and treated as multiple filenames. (These commands are written using `\`` `\`` syntax, but the problem fully applies when using the `$(` `)` syntax as well.)