# How to enable the double star ** (globstar) operator?

Tags: command-line, bash

I know that there is an operator similar to the `*`, with the difference that it works into all the sub-directories.

Assume you have a folder structure:

```
.
├── bar
│   ├── foo
│   │   └── baz
│   │       └── hurz
│   │           └── lolz
│   │               └── hello.txt
│   └── poit.txt
└── fnord.txt
```

Then `ls` with single star `*` would list:

```
$ ls *.txt
fnord.txt
```

I expect the double star operator `**` to work on the subfolders, yet it is not complete. I know that this can work as I had this enabled on another machine yet I forgot how.

```
$ ls **/*.txt
bar/poit.txt
```

I was expecting the output to look like:

```
ls **/*.txt
bar/foo/baz/hurz/lolz/hello.txt  bar/poit.txt  fnord.txt
```

How is the `**` operator called and how do I activate it properly?

Comment: @dessert Not a duplicate as in that question the globstar is one of many possible solutions, whereas this question is about enabling the globstar specifically.

Comment: I beg to differ: It's true you wrote the question to point in that direction only, but the other question still tries to achieve the very same goal *and* its answers apply to your problem: One could add an answer “You can do the same with `find` as follows: …” here as well.

Comment: Duplicate on Unix & Linux: [Recursive glob?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49913/117037)

Comment: "Yet now I expect the double star operator to work on the subfolders" Why?

Comment: @muru Because I had it working in the past, yet didn't know how to activate in anymore.

Comment: While question is related to linked duplicate, it is indeed  bash-specific. End result being same, doesn't imply it is strictly duplicate.  That said, however, the question being closed doesn't significantly impact anyone and cross-linking related questions in one way or another still makes a post useful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are looking for the globstar shell option which was introduced in bash version 4.

If you unsure what version you are running you can test that via:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release
```

Check if it is enabled via:

```
$ shopt globstar
```

It defaults to `off`. If you want to use it you have to enable it:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
```

Then it will work as expected. You might want to add this to your `.bashrc` for it to be always enabled in new shells.

To disable it:

```
$ shopt -u globstar
```

See `help shopt` for details.

Comment: Works great but needs to be enabled every time I start a new terminal, how do you permanently enable it?

Comment: @protango add it to your .bashrc file. For more info:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work