# Can the "rename" command distinguish between directories and files?

Tags: command-line, directory, rename

I need to rename only directories and not files, and I want to do it with `rename`.

Is there any way to do it?

It says nothing in the manual about differentiating between directories and files.

This command changes everything, no matter directory or files:

```
rename 's/ /\n/g' *
```

This command solved my problem:

```
rename 's/ /\n/g' */
```

I need a slash behind it.

Comment: Those links are helpful to me.

Comment: Have you answered your own question in the question? The trailing slash requires less typing than any method that could have been provided by the developers of `rename`... I suggest you remove that part of your question and post it as an answer!

Comment: but this only partly answers the question (at least the title). How to chose only files?

Comment: by the way ... I would not recommend using newlines in file/folder names. It may cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: Why does it cause problems? It really looks better and cleaner.

Comment: @JulianLai It causes problems for people that use `ls | wc -l` to count the number of objects, or generally when parsing the output of `ls` -- which is discouraged, but widely done.

Comment: and many many more things.

Answer (score 3):

`rename` does not distinguish between files and folders.

---

The shell is responsible for expanding the wildcard `*` into files and folders.

- `*` will be expanded to all non-hidden files and folders.
- `*/` will be expanded to all non-hidden folders.

But I don't know of any way to expand to files only. You can use `find -exec` instead.

only folders:

```bsh
rename 's/ /\n/g' */
```

or

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rename 's/ /\n/g' {} +
```

Only files:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rename 's/ /\n/g' {} +
```

Note that `find` will also find [hidden files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266179/how-to-exclude-ignore-hidden-files-and-directories-in-a-wildcard-embedded-find) unlike `*` (unless you turn on the `dotglob` shell option by running `shopt -s dotglob`).

---

`zsh` seems to be able to [match files only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189069/how-can-i-use-a-wildcard-to-match-just-files-not-directories) with wildcards.

---

> **Disclaimer**: I would not recommend adding newlines to file names as it may cause trouble and break many scripts.